# Separate groups in a ggplot heatmap by adding a black column between them

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I have a dataframe:

```
gene_symbol <- c("sads", "sdsds", "sdasdad", "dfds", "sdsdd")
panel <- c("big", "big", "big", "gr", "sm")
variable <- c("x", "x", "y", "z", "y")
value <- c("normal", "over", "low", "normal", "low")
colors <- c("red", "green", "yellow", "red", "red")

HG44 <- data.frame(gene_symbol, panel, variable, value, colors)
HG44$gene_symbol <- factor(HG44$gene_symbol, levels = unique(HG44$gene_symbol))
```

and I create a heatmap with:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

pp <- ggplot(HG44, aes(gene_symbol, variable)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Calibri", 
                                   size = 11, angle = 45, hjust = 1))

library(plotly)

ggplotly(pp)
```

As you can see the first 3 gene symbols belong to the `panel` "big" and the other 2 to the other 2 `panel` respectively. I would like somehow to separate those grouped gene symbols without using `facet.grid()`. I am thinking of adding an empty black column in the end of every group which will separate them from the others and will have the name of each `panel` at the top or at the bottom.

Comment: *"the first 3 gene symbols belong to the panel "big" and the other 2 to the other 2 panel respectively"* I don't see a panel named "big", nor do I see *any* panels. It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Can you provide a mock-up of your expected output plot?

Comment: Also, what does `plotly` has to do with your question?

Comment: When you plot the heatmap you see that "sads","dfds" and"sdsdd" are displayed first and they belong to the panel type "big". I delelted library(plotly). It was thereby mistake.

Comment: What you're asking is exactly what faceting does, why you don't want to use it?

Comment: I re edited in order to show that the first 3 genes belong to "big". Faceting does not respond well with ggplotly() as I cannot set the column width. I have already asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51444351/how-to-make-the-column-widths-of-a-grouped-heatmap-all-the-same-in-ggplotly

Comment: I guess that `fill = panel` instead of `fill = value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can use `geom_vline` function to separate these groups. See as below:

```
gene_symbol <- c("sads", "sdsds", "sdasdad","dfds","sdsdd")
panel <- c("big", "big", "big", "gr", "sm")
variable <- c("x","x","y","z","y")
value <- c("normal", "over", "low", "normal", "low")
colors <- c("red", "green", "yellow", "red", "red")

HG44 <- data.frame(gene_symbol, panel, variable, value, colors)
HG44$gene_symbol <- factor(HG44$gene_symbol, levels = unique(HG44$gene_symbol))

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

pp <- ggplot(HG44, aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Calibri", size = 11, angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(3.5, 4.5), size = 2)

library(plotly)
ggplotly(pp)
```

Output:
[image: Genes separated]